# How to initialize a Queue (linked list) and insert an element?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, linked-list, queue

I have an assignment where I have to create a linked list and add and remove items from it. I'm having a problem understanding how to initialize the linked list in my constructor and adding items to it as well.

Here's my header file for it.

```
#ifndef CONGERA3_H
#define CONGERA3_H

const int MAX_STRING = 6;
typedef char Element300[MAX_STRING + 1];

class Queue300
{
    public:

    Queue300 ();
    Queue300 (Queue300 &old);
    ~Queue300();
    void enQueue300 (const Element300);
    void deQueue300 (Element300);
    void view300();

private:
    struct Node300;
    typedef Node300 * NodePtr300;
    struct Node300
    {
        Element300 element;
        NodePtr300 next;
    };
    NodePtr300 front, rear;
};

#endif
```

Here's my implementation file as well. I've removed the other functions for now, I feel like if I can get the constructor and enQueue down I can figure out the rest of them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "congera3.h"
using namespace std;

Queue300::Queue300 ()
{
    front = NULL;

    return;
}

void Queue300::enQueue300 (const Element300 element)
{
   Node300 temp;
   temp.element = element;
}
```

I feel like I need to add a lot more to the constructor, such as setting the rear to point to the front. In the enQueue I think I need to have rear point towards the element I'm passing in and then have that element's next point towards front.

Comment: *I'm having a problem understanding how to initialize the linked list in my constructor and adding items to it as well.* -- Advice -- before writing one line of code, you should have drawn on paper, boxes and lines, a linked list and how the various operations would be done.  Trying to do this without this prerequisite almost always results in failure in writing the code correctly.

Comment: I have a few things drawn out for it that we did in class but none of them are helping.

Comment: For assignments involving linked lists (and any data structure) you must have a plan on paper before writing any code.  Otherwise what may end up happening is that you write code, and then you've coded yourself into a corner and can't escape without scrapping a lot, if not all of the code you had written.